# how to set post order by dynamically WORDPRESS

Tags: wordpress, plugins

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k87Jw.png)

Hello guys

I have created a custom post type and a variety of custom fields. I wanted to control the order of each of these post so I created a custom field called "Order". At the moment I just manually enter a number into this field for the position I want the post to be in the list. The problem with doing this is if I say want to move post 8 to position 3 I would need to go into every post and change the order accordingly.

here example:
https://prnt.sc/vua6dm

**I need to change the order of posts individually which will also change the frontend.**

Comment: Is Order a custom field?

Comment: yes i want this functionality

Comment: any idea how to make  this

Comment: You can check out the source code of this plugin which seems to do the ordering by drag and drop UI. https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-types-order/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a metabox called order and then the following code:

```
<?php
$price_query_args = array(
  'meta_key' => 'order',
  'meta_value' => "",
  'meta_compare' => '!=',
  'post_type' => array('post'),
);
<?php if (have_posts()):?>
  <ul style="display:flex;">
 <?php  while (have_posts()):the_post();?>
        <li style="order:<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'order', true); ?>;" >
       <img src="<?php $image=wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id( $post -> ID ),'single-post-thumbnail' ); echo $image[0]; ?>" style="width:100%">
        <label class="order"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></label>
          <div class="btn-pro" >
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>/#tab1">bulk</a>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>/#tab2">pack</a>
          </div>
        </li>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  </ul>
  <?php endif; ?>
```